# Can you have an ARIMA(1,1,0)x(0,1,0)12 model?

Tags: time-series, arima

If d, or D is set to non-zero in the model ARIMA(p,d,q)x(P,D,Q), does one of {p,q} or {P,Q} have to be set to non-zero too respectively?

Comment: no. (leaving this as a comment, because I don't have time for the fuller explanation that would be helpful to s5s)

Comment: @zbicyclist Sorry, it's ambiguous - No to "Can you have an ARIMA(1,1,0)x(0,1,0)" or no to "Does one of {p,q} or {P,Q} have to be set to non-zero?"

Comment: No to "does one of {p,q} or {P,Q} have to be set to non-zero".   You can have an ARIMA(1,1,0)x(0,1,0).